# php variables - best way to pass variables over to another php page

Tags: php, web-deployment

So I am aware of these two common ways of passing variables across php pages.

**1. PHP SESSIONS**

I understand that `$_SESSION` is a php global variable that can hold variables across php pages during the session of the browser.

It works well but my concern with it is if a user for what ever reasons, decides to type the url of a page or goes into their history and accesses a url page for the website, the $_SESSION variable may not be set, if it was expecting the user to get to this page from a set route/path.

In addition, if a user goes into another page, and the page sets an already defined $_SESSION to another value, and then decides to go back to the previous page, the $_SESSION variable is not correct for that page, causing many errors.

**2. URL passing**

This is by far the most reliable in my opinion. The only concern I have with this, is the pages can get rather messy with long URL's.

```
page1.php?postId={variable goes here}
```

passing 4,5 or 6 variables can get a bit messy, I also need to encode then or encrypt them. The URL can get rather long, and I am not sure how I feel about passing variables across the URL.

**My Question:**

What is the best way to pass variables from one php page to another. Are the two methods above the best way to go about it, or is there another my efficient way. Also if efficiency isn't the issue, then what is the most secure procedure/method.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i use different ways depending on the situation, there's no "best" way for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely going to depend what you're trying to do? `$_SESSION` variables and `$_GET` variables largely have different purposes in web programming (although, yes, you could force some sway between the two).

The question you need to ask yourself is *"is the variable storing information on the user OR directing the webserver to do something"* if it's the former then use `$_SESSION` if it's the latter then `$_GET`.

You wouldn't for example want to pass `loggedon=true` as a `GET` variable (ignoring the security implications) because you would have to update *every single link on the page* to have the query string appended to it which, as you say, would lead to some untidy URLs.

**SESSION**

Is most commonly used for storing information about a user. Some examples:

1. Log on status
2. Shopping basket
3. Session preferences

For example when a user is successfully logged on you will want some way to remember that between page loads:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["loggedon"] = true;
```

In every subsequent page request you can then check:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["loggedon"] ?? null){
    echo "ERROR: You shouldn't be here!";
    exit;
}
```

Note that `$_SESSION` is only accessible to the server, can't be directly accessed by the website user, and is persistent until the session closes.

**GET**

On the other hand is sent with every request and is typically used when you want to pass *non-sensitive* information from the user to the webserver. Some examples:

1. Language preferences
2. User input (e.g. a search query when using a search engine)
3. Forgotten password secure codes

Suppose you have a cookery website and 1000 recipes. You would likely only have one page to show the recipe and pass a `GET` variable in the URL to indicate which recipe should be loaded

```
http://www.mycookingwebsite.com/recipe.php?recipeid=477
```

Note that `GET` requests are visible to the user, can be modified, and show up in history etc. as well.

**N.B.** Do not pass **sensitive** details (e.g. username/password) over `GET` - not least because they would show up in the browser history!

---

You mention passing variables from one page to another. But I'm not quite clear on whether you mean Server->Server (`SESSION`) OR Client->Server(`GET`)?

An example of this all coming together would be in the case of a shopping cart:

At the back end you have an array stored in your session with the items in the cart, this is persistent throughout the session. On the client side you have the ability to send a `GET` (most people would probably `POST`) request to tell the server about the new product you want to add to the list.

---

If your primary concern is that users may *find themselves at the wrong "stage"* then I suggest building in some checks to make sure that they are in the right place at the right time.

For example given a quiz with 10 questions... If the user clicks a link which drops them at question 5 you check to see if they've already answered questions 1-4 and then act appropriately depending on the answer.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks! Most of my passing involve the id of some table in my database. So i a m building a posts page, where users can see posts and replies etc. I need to pass the postID to the next page for example, but I feel sending such information about the database isn't so good. Then with ``$_SESSION`` the issue I have is if the user loads are part of the website where it requires the $SESSION to be set, then that can cause problems. Right now I am redirecting to the home page if this is the case.

Comment: For example, look at stack overflow. The URL has 1 variable. How does it know what to use for this page. Does it use $SESSIONS?

Comment: Most websites use the example shown for the "recipe" in the answer. For example with stackoverflow it has the question id as a get (all be it in a pretty URL format) and looks it up in the database. If you have a post system then I suggest that's what you do too. I'm not sure what you mean by "if the user loads part of the website that requires $_SESSION to be set" if you mean secure/logged on areas then just check they're supposed to be there and kick them out with `header('location:/some_page.php')` if not?